# Understanding RF MOSFET Bias Circuit

Tags: rf, repair, ham-radio

A faulty in vehicle DCDC charger has fed 16V or so into a brand new radio and I'm stuck with a non-transmitting transmitter.

This particular circuit has multiple amplification stages with two preamps and a 'drive amp', before driving large RF MOSFETs (100W). Following the signal though everything looks fine until I hit the gate of the final preamp, the drive amp. The FET is an unusual Mitsubishi part: RD15HVF1, and the signal on the gate reads 5Vpp with no offset; I don't believe this is enough for the FET to conduct.

The circuit has a bias that's driven by a digital ADC which appears to be outputting nothing (unsure of the logic here), however, it if it were to output a voltage, what would the effect on the gate signal be given the schematic below? Would it pull the voltage up and be additive?

This is an Icom IC-7100 by the way

[image]
[image]

Comment: *The circuit has a bias that's driven by a digital ADC which appears to be outputting nothing* That does not make sense, for that MOSFET to work, it needs to be biased and looking at the schematic, the ADC needs to output the DC voltage for that. If there is no DC voltage at the gate of the MOSFET (I would expect 5 V or more) then that ADC is broken and/or it doesn't get a proper input signal.

Comment: Biasing a MOSFET using an ADC makes perfect sense in this application, it allows the biasing of the MOSFET to be changed so that the RF gain and RF power output can be changed.